# Python regex for number with or without decimals using a dot or comma as separator?

Tags: python, regex

I'm just learning regex and now I'm trying to match a number which more or less represents this:

```
[zero or more numbers][possibly a dot or comma][zero or more numbers]
```

No dot or comma is also okay. So it should match the following:

```
1
123
123.
123.4
123.456
.456
123,  # From here it's the same but with commas instead of dot separators
123,4
123,456
,456
```

But it should not match the following:

```
0.,1
0a,1
0..1
1.1.2
100,000.99  # I know this and the one below are valid in many languages, but I simply want to reject these
100.000,99
```

So far I've come up with `[0-9]*[.,][0-9]*`, but it doesn't seem to work so well:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile("[0-9]*[.,][0-9]*")
>>> if r.match('0.1.'): print 'it matches!'
...
it matches!
>>> if r.match('0.abc'): print 'it matches!'
...
it matches!
```

I have the feeling I'm doing two things wrong: I don't use match correctly AND my regex is not correct. Could anybody enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to make `[.,]` part as optional by adding `?` after that character class and also don't forget to add anchors. `^` asserts that we are at the start and `$` asserts that we are at the end.

```
^\d*[.,]?\d*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/25)

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r"^\d*[.,]?\d*$")
>>> if r.match('0.1.'): print 'it matches!'
... 
>>> if r.match('0.abc'): print 'it matches!'
... 
>>> if r.match('0.'): print 'it matches!'
... 
it matches!
```

If you don't want to allow a single comma or dot then use  a lookahead.

```
^(?=.*?\d)\d*[.,]?\d*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/26)

Comment: what's the meaning for `[possibly a dot or comma]` ? And also if you have any queries, ask it to the op for clarification.

Comment: op didn't mention a comma or dot in the not matching list. I already told , if you have any doubts then ask it to the op.

Comment: Good to mention that case in your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Your regex would work fine if you just add the ^ at the front and the $ at the back so that system knows how your string would begin and end.

Try this

```
^[0-9]*[.,]{0,1}[0-9]*$

import re

checklist = ['1', '123', '123.', '123.4', '123.456', '.456', '123,', '123,4', '123,456', ',456', '0.,1', '0a,1', '0..1', '1.1.2', '100,000.99', '100.000,99', '0.1.', '0.abc']

pat = re.compile(r'^[0-9]*[.,]{0,1}[0-9]*$')

for c in checklist:
   if pat.match(c):
      print '%s : it matches' % (c)
   else:
      print '%s : it does not match' % (c)

1 : it matches
123 : it matches
123. : it matches
123.4 : it matches
123.456 : it matches
.456 : it matches
123, : it matches
123,4 : it matches
123,456 : it matches
,456 : it matches
0.,1 : it does not match
0a,1 : it does not match
0..1 : it does not match
1.1.2 : it does not match
100,000.99 : it does not match
100.000,99 : it does not match
0.1. : it does not match
0.abc : it does not match
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are asking for a partial match, as long as it starts at the beginning.

One way around this is to end the regex in `\Z` (optionally `$`).

> `\Z`  Matches only at the end of the string.

and the other is to use `re.fullmatch` instead.

```
import re
help(re.match)
#>>> Help on function match in module re:
#>>>
#>>> match(pattern, string, flags=0)
#>>>     Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
#>>>     a match object, or None if no match was found.
#>>>
```

vs

```
import re
help(re.fullmatch)
#>>> Help on function fullmatch in module re:
#>>>
#>>> fullmatch(pattern, string, flags=0)
#>>>     Try to apply the pattern to all of the string, returning
#>>>     a match object, or None if no match was found.
#>>>
```

Note that `fullmatch` is new in 3.4.

You should also make the `[.,]` part optional, so append a `?` to that.

> `'?'` Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE. ab? will match either ‘a’ or ‘ab’.

Eg.

```
import re
r = re.compile("[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]*\Z")

bool(r.match('0.1.'))
#>>> False

bool(r.match('0.abc'))
#>>> False

bool(r.match('0123'))
#>>> True
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
(?:^|[^\d,.])\d*(?:[,.]\d+)?(?:$|[^\d,.])
```

If you don't want empty string:

```
(?:^|[^\d,.])\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?(?:$|[^\d,.])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.?\d)(?!(.*?\.){2,})[\d.]+$|^(?=.?\d)(?!(.*?,){2,})[\d,]+$
```

Try this.Validates all cases.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hS3dT7/9

Comment: Yours allows single `.` or `,` [to be matched](http://regex101.com/r/lZ0sV5/1) :p but don't know if such case should verify or not.

Comment: :) thieeeef! plus for the working one. Of course a bit of explanation would be awesome.

Comment: @Jonny5 the one which got 2 up also has this flaw.Your is actually the best and should be d ans.But the world is not fair :(

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas for verifying a non-empty match:

1.) Use of a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check for at least one digit:

```
^(?=.?\d)\d*[.,]?\d*$
```

- From `^` [start](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to  `$` [end](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).
- `(?=.?\d)` matches if `,1`, `1`,...
- `\d*[.,]?\d*` Allowed sequence: `\d*` any amount of digits, followed by one `[.,]`, `\d*`
- Note, that the first `.` inside the lookahead is a [metacharacter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) that stands for *any character*, whereas the other inside the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[.,]` matches a literal `.`

Instead of the positive lookahead also a negative one could be used: `^(?!\D*$)\d*[.,]?\d*$`

[Test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uN7iC7/4), [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

---

2.) Use 2 different patterns:

```
^(?:\d+[.,]\d*|[.,]?\d+)$
```

- `(?:` Starts a [non-capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group) for the alternation.
- `\d+[.,]\d*` for matching `1.`, `1,1`,... `|` OR
- `[.,]?\d+` for matching `1`, `,1`...

[Test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uN7iC7/2)

Answer (score 0):

If the two decimal places are mandatory, you could use the following:

```
^((\d){1,3},*){1,5}\.(\d){2}$
```

This will match the following pattern:

- 1.00
- 10.00
- 100.00
- 1,000.00
- 10,000.00
- 100,000.00
- 1,000,000.00

Comment: This is matching `12,,,,,,,,,,,,,,.34`

Answer (score 0):

More generic method can be as follows

```
import re
r=re.compile(r"^\d\d*[,]?\d*[,]?\d*[.,]?\d*\d$")
print(bool(r.match('100,000.00')))
```

This will match the following pattern:

1. This will match the following pattern:

   - 100
   - 1,000
   - 100.00
   - 1,000.00
   - 1,00,000
   - 1,00,000.00
2. This will **not** match the following pattern:

   - .100
   - ..100
   - 100.100.00
   - ,100
   - 100,
   - 100.

Comment: This is matching `1,,.2`

Comment: Yeah.. Need to prevent those cases like repeatedly coming commas or dots. I'm using this matching on extracted (using ocr) text for validation. Since there is a very less chance of these cases in OCR'ed text, this worked for me. This is not perfect for validation of user inputs. Thanks @Toto for providing your feedback

Answer (score 0):

ok, the regex that I use to check for integers with thousands seperators, that may or may not include a decimal part, and then one without a decimal part, goes like this:

(this is python 3.10.8 I'm using, not sure which version regex, thoough.)

> r"^(?:\-)?(\d{1,3}(?:(?:\.(?=\d.+\,?)|\,(?=\d.+\.?))\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d+\.\d+|\d+)$"

I hope this helps.