# Getting all str type elements in a pd.DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Based on my little knowledge on `pandas`，`pandas.Series.str.contains` can search a  specific str in `pd.Series`. But what if the dataframe is large and I just want to glance all kinds of str element in it before I do anything?

Example like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,2,3,'+'],'x2':[2,'a','c','this is']})
    x1  x2
0   1   2
1   2   a
2   3   c
3   +   this is
```

I need a function to return `['+','a','c','this is']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking strictly at what are string values and performance is not a concern, then this is a very simple answer.

```
df.where(df.applymap(type).eq(str)).stack().tolist()

['a', 'c', '+', 'this is']
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 possible ways - check numeric values saved as strings or not.

Check difference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,'2.78','3','+'],'x2':[2.8,'a','c','this is'], 'x3':[1,4,5,4]}) 
print (df)
     x1       x2  x3
0     1      2.8   1
1  2.78        a   4 <-2.78 is float saved as string
2     3        c   5 <-3 is int saved as string
3     +  this is   4

#flatten all values
ar = df.values.ravel()
#errors='coerce' parameter in pd.to_numeric return NaNs for non numeric
L = np.unique(ar[np.isnan(pd.to_numeric(ar, errors='coerce'))]).tolist()
print (L)
['+', 'a', 'c', 'this is']
```

Another solution is use custom function for check if possible convert to `float`s:

```
def is_not_float_try(str):
    try:
        float(str)
        return False
    except ValueError:
        return True

s = df.stack()
L = s[s.apply(is_not_float_try)].unique().tolist()
print (L)
['a', 'c', '+', 'this is']
```

If need all values saved as strings use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
s = df.stack()
L = s[s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))].unique().tolist()
print (L)
['2.78', 'a', '3', 'c', '+', 'this is']
```

Comment: This is the best way, IMHO

Comment: @AmiTavory - Thank you.

Comment: It's elegence. I have used `df.apply(lambda x:pd.to_numeric(x,errors='ignore'))` to transform str-numeric like `'1.23'` to `1.23`, so I can tell your function would work on this example. But `np.unique()` may fail if there are lists elements in dataframe. I will vote for you.

Comment: @Garvey - Thank you. `np.unique` should be omit, it is not necessary.

Comment: @Garvey - I am thinking Ìf use `errors='ignore')` how is possible check numeric? Because if `errors='coerce')` it create `NaN`s and possible check it.

Comment: @jezrael Well, I set `errors=ignore` on purpose to convert something like `'1.23'` to `1.23` first, which is unrelevent to this question. After that, I realized it necessary to glance what kinds of str were still contained in the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can using `str.isdigit` with `unstack`

```
df[df.apply(lambda x : x.str.isdigit()).eq(0)].unstack().dropna().tolist()
Out[242]: ['+', 'a', 'c', 'this is']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions and set union, could try something like

```
>>> set.union(*[set(df[c][~df[c].str.findall('[^\d]+').isnull()].unique()) for c in df.columns])
{'+', 'a', 'c', 'this is'}
```

If you use a [regular expression for a number in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137955/python-regex-for-number-with-or-without-decimals-using-a-dot-or-comma-as-separat), you could omit floating point numbers as well.

Comment: Nice to see you answering questions (-:

Comment: @piRSquared You too! Your rep has grown tremeeeeeeeeeeeeendously!